# Repeated crashes of 'suggestd'

Tags: macos, crash

I've been running OS X 10.11 without issues since it was released — until today, when `suggestd` began repeatedly crashing (from every few minutes, up to every 30 seconds).

What is `suggestd` and how do I disable it (since it's only function appears to be to crash)?

---

```
Process:               suggestd [23293]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSuggestions.framework/Versions/A/Support/suggestd
Identifier:            suggestd
Version:               1.0 (354.10)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           suggestd [23293]
User ID:               501

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.rtcreportingd

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'RTC config incorrect - no backends found;'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: [looking at this thread at Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7264893), it suggests to do something with your new "`~/Library/Suggestions/`" folder.  However, in my just updated-to-MacOS10.11 machine, I don't have a Suggestions folder in there.  And SIP (System Integrity Protection) is refusing to allow me to create an empty one.  I'm getting tempted to downgrade back to Yosemite.

Comment: after disabling SIP and managing to create a "`Suggestions`" folder, my constantly appearing crash logs for suggestd stopped.  yay!

Comment: @MichaelDautermann: Wow, I hope that's not the only fix. I'm reluctant to mess with what Apple just locked down. I worry will create other problems down the road.

Comment: Are you still on 10.11.0? Have Apple fixed this in a dot update without you messing with SIP? Also ~/Library is **not under SIP restrictions** so what folder are you creating @MichaelDautermann

Answer (score 8):

I turned off Contact's new "Show Contacts Found In Mail" feature (Contacts > Preferences > General > "Show Contacts Found In Mail" or "Show Contacts Found In Apps" in later versions of macOS), and that seems to have shut down `suggestd` crashes in my log. That also deleted `~/Library/Suggestions/harvestqueueold`, which was previously filled by what looked like a bunch of temporary files. I'm going to try turning it back on now and see if the crashes resume.

Comment: On macOS 10.12.6 the checkbox in the Contacts.app preferences is labeled "Show contacts found in Apps".

Comment: On macOS 10.14.6 the checkbox in the Contacts app General preferences is labeled “Show contacts Siri found in apps”

Answer (score 2):

I am running High Sierra and `suggestd` was crashing every 30 seconds. None of the suggestions above helped. I tried to stop `suggestd` but SIP stopped me from doing that. I ended up doing the following which seems to have stopped the problem. I edited the `com.apple.suggestd.plist` file and went to the MachServices dictionary and set all of the services to NO. This basically turns off `suggestd`. To do this  is a bit complicated because the file is locked by SIP, here are the steps.

1. Restart into recovery mode. This can be done by restarting and holding the ‘Command’ and ‘R’ keys. Release these keys as soon as you see the Apple logo and ‘loading’ bar.
2. Once your Mac is in recovery mode, select ‘Utilities’ from the menu bar, followed by ‘Terminal.’
3. In the Terminal window, enter the following command: `csrutil disable` this will turn off SIP
4. Restart
5. Open a terminal and `cd` to `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`
6. Change the permission on the directory to write for anyone by running `sudo chmod a+w .`
7. Change the permission on the file `com.apple.suggestd.plist' to write for anyone by running`sudo chmod a+w com.apple.suggestd.plist`
8. Open the file in Xcode
9. Expand the dictionary `MachServices` and change every entry to 'NO'
10. Save the file
11. Restart into recovery mode. This can be done by restarting and holding the ‘Command’ and ‘R’ keys. Release these keys as soon as you see the Apple logo and ‘loading’ bar.
12. Once your Mac is in recovery mode, select ‘Utilities’ from the menu bar, followed by ‘Terminal.’
13. In the Terminal window, enter the following command: `csrutil enable` this will turn SIP back on
14. Restart

Since I did this procedure `suggestd` has not crashed (because it is not being used) and I have not seen any difference in any functionality.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful. This suddently started happening to me on Mojave circa Nov 2021, and note that others on Mojave were hit by it at the same time [see [link](https://twitter.com/rgriff/status/1458632591423070212)]
I would add after step 10 to change the permissions back to what they were:
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/LaunchAgents/
sudo chmod 644 com.apple.suggestd.plist

also after step 7 you might want to duplicate the file and rename it as a backup (com.apple.suggestd.plist.bk, for example.)

Comment: grr… the problem continues after making the edits in MachServices, tho not as frequently.  Anything else to change?  There's a dictionary entry called "EnableTransactions" at the same level as MachServices and it's currently "YES". Maybe that was added since High Sierra?